# How to prevent "abc" (text-based) hints from being on the top of suggestions list

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

[image]

You could see hints on the picture above when I type `def`. The problem is that the hint on the top doesn't do anything (if I click `Tab` or `Enter` it just returns `def`) but the hint below creates a method like:

```
def (method_name)
  ()
end
```

How could I remove (or down in priority) hint on the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // Controls whether snippets are shown with other suggestions and how
>   they are sorted.
>    //  - top: Show snippet suggestions on top of other
>   suggestions.
>   //  - bottom: Show snippet suggestions below other
>   suggestions.
>   //  - inline: Show snippets suggestions with other
>   suggestions.
>   //  - none: Do not show snippet suggestions.

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

will move your snippets to the top of the suggestions list and

> // Controls whether completions should be computed based on words in
>   the document.

```
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
```

will remove suggestions that are derived solely from other text in the file (hence the little "abc" in the box preceding your first "def" - that means it is text-based and not snippet-based for example).